# Prevent external display from charging MacBook battery while plugged in via USB-C

Tags: display, battery

Is it possible to prevent charging the MacBook's battery when it is plugged in to an external display?

I am currently using the LG UltraFine 5K 27MD5KL-B and would prefer to choose when it should serve as a display only and when it should also charge the MacBook's battery. My main concern being battery longevity reduction because of constant loading at maximum charge.

Comment: If you're running macOS Big Sur (or newer) there's a feature called "Optimise battery charging" that at least partially solves your issue: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212049

Comment: There seems to be a software that claims to do this, however I do not have any experience with it: https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente